# Событие в WPF MouseLeftButtonUp или его аналоги

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка на событие MouseLeftButtonDown срабатывает некоторое событие, при MouseLeftButtonUp должно обрываться первое событие, но если я зажал на кнопке, чуть отодвинул мышь за приделы кнопки это событие не сработает?

я продублировал его событием MouseLeave, но мне кажется это не совсем правильно?
вся манипуляция с данными выполняется в ViewModel а не в codebehind